# Getting Working Days Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the working days between two date.
Example: stdate = 28/10/2011 and endate = 04/11/2011. This should be 6 working days, but its only giving 5 days.

```
var workingdays = 0;
var weekday     = new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

while (stdate <= endate) 
{
    var day = weekday[stdate.getDay()];
    if(day != "Saturday" && day != "Sunday") 
    {
        workingdays++; 
    }
    console.log(weekday[stdate.getDay()]);
    stdate = new Date(stdate.getTime() + 86400000); 
}
```

The console log shows the results below.

```
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
```

Sunday shows twice for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you pass your dates (start and end) to the javascript? DO you convert a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daylight savings time.

As you are adding 24 hours to the date, it's not enough to get you to the next day on the sunday, as that particular sunday has 25 hours.

You should add a day instead of adding hours:

```
stdate = new Date(stdate.getFullYear(), stdate.getMonth(), stdate.getDate() + 1);
```

Explanation: When you call the `Date` constructor with a date that is out of range, it will automaticall wrap to the next month, i.e. `new Date(2010,9,32)` gives you the first of November.

Answer (score 12):

Here you go:

```
 function getWorkingDays(startDate, endDate){
     var result = 0;

    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= endDate)  {  

        var weekDay = currentDate.getDay();
        if(weekDay != 0 && weekDay != 6)
            result++;

         currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1); 
    }

    return result;
 }

 var begin = new Date(2011, 09, 8);
 var end = new Date(2011, 09, 25);
 alert(getWorkingDays(begin, end)); // result = 12 days
```

Keep in mind that the month indication for the two variables is zero based. So in my example we are looking at october (month 10).

Comment: i changed var currentDate = startDate; to var currentDate = new Date(startDate.getTime()); to avoid mutation of the startDate variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
stdate.setDate(stdate.getDate()+1);
```

in place of

```
stdate = new Date(stdate.getTime() + 86400000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date of week from StartDate and EndDate

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var object = [];


    function getTuesday(startDate, endDate, n) {

        var currentDate = startDate;
        while (currentDate <= endDate) {
            if (weekday[currentDate.getDay()] === weekday[n])
                object.push(currentDate + "\n");
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        } return object;
    }

    var begin = new Date(2015, 11, 08);

    var end = new Date(2016, 01, 08);

    alert(getTuesday(begin, end, 3) + "\n Total date or week: " + object.length);
```