# Calculate working days with JavaScript taking into account holidays

Tags: javascript, date

How can I adapt the code in thus question to take into account national holidays.

[Getting Working Days Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952239/getting-working-days-using-javascript)

I know I will need an array of dates which are holidays but what needs to be added into the logic ?

Comment: You'll need to post some code showing what you have so far, otherwise you're simply asking someone to build this for you. Here's a feed of various US public holidays: http://www.webcal.fi/en-US/other_file_formats.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the array of holidays may actually not be the easiest part of the story.

Anyway, I'm going to assume that you eventually end up with an array of dates in `[ year, month, day ]` format. Storing full `Date` objects in there is another possibility, which may or may not be better suited depending on your import method.

Below is a very simplified and obviously incomplete one:

```
const holidays = [
  [ 2015,  1,  1 ], [ 2015,  1, 19 ], [ 2015,  7,  4 ], [ 2015, 12, 25 ],
  [ 2016,  1,  1 ], [ 2016,  1, 18 ], [ 2016,  7,  4 ], [ 2016, 12, 25 ],
  [ 2017,  1,  1 ], [ 2017,  1, 16 ], [ 2017,  7,  4 ], [ 2017, 12, 25 ]
];
```

And here is some code to help you get started:

```js
const holidays = [
  [ 2015,  1,  1 ], [ 2015,  1, 19 ], [ 2015,  7,  4 ], [ 2015, 12, 25 ],
  [ 2016,  1,  1 ], [ 2016,  1, 18 ], [ 2016,  7,  4 ], [ 2016, 12, 25 ],
  [ 2017,  1,  1 ], [ 2017,  1, 16 ], [ 2017,  7,  4 ], [ 2017, 12, 25 ]
];

function isHoliday(ts) {
  var year  = ts.getFullYear(),
      month = ts.getMonth(),
      day   = ts.getDate();

  return holidays.some(function(d) {
    return d[0] == year && d[1] == month + 1 && d[2] == day;
  });
}

function getWorkingDays(ts, end) {
  for(var cnt = 0; ts.getTime() <= end.getTime(); ts.setDate(ts.getDate() + 1)) {
    // increment counter if this day is neither a Sunday,
    // nor a Saturday, nor a holiday
    if(ts.getDay() != 0 && ts.getDay() != 6 && !isHoliday(ts)) {
      cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}

console.log(getWorkingDays(new Date('2015-12-20'), new Date('2016-01-03')));
console.log(getWorkingDays(new Date('2016-12-20'), new Date('2017-01-03')));
```